# Creating C# SqlGeography point with Z value?

Tags: sql-server, geography-data-type

In C#, there appears to be only one method to create a SqlGeography Point object. It takes a lat/lon and SRID. But it can also have a Z and M value.

How are these created?

The Point class is immutable, so I would think you can only pass this when creating the Point.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the static/class method [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.parse.aspx) to create a point from an Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT) representation.  For example

```
var myZMPoint = SqlGeography.Parse("POINT ZM (1 1 5 60)")
```

There are other class methods that might also work.